# How we can clone spring boot Microservice in IntelliJ from GitHub? Please Explain whole process

Tags: github, intellij-idea, merge, microservices, clone

If I am using and following below medium blog but I am not able to create a proper project. It is creating issues for me after changes or after some time. Because we imported a new module in the empty project then it creates a different location and import module from a different location.
https://medium.com/backend-habit/intellij-idea-running-multiple-project-microservices-in-one-workspace-d61126fe0eef

Comment: >It is creating issues for me after changes or after some time

Could you please elaborate what exactly seems to be the issue? The article that you are referring to contains all steps.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open the Github repo and copy the HTTPS URL of the repo to be cloned.

[image: Sample Github repo]

Step 2: [Open Intellij](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBVOAnygcZw) and select the **Get from VCS** button

[image: Intelliji]

Step 3: Paste the Repo Git URL in the provided input window then click on the **Clone** button

[image: URL input window on intelliji]

Step 4: The Repo is now cloned into your Intelliji IDE and ready

[image: Clones movies repo now in Intelliji]

It may also be beneficial to [enable Auto import](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/tutorial/project-setup) in Intelliji to resolve the import of Java classes.

Step 5: Select the repo from the recently added on Intelliji and you are good to go.

[image: Open project]